Transfer function, zeros and poles of the circuit

I am trying to determine the transfer function $$H(s)=v_{OUT}(s)/v_{in}(s)$$, zeros and poles of the transfer function of the above circuit.
From the obtained form of the transfer function H(s) as the voltage gain $$H(s)=K_{U}(s)=v_{OUT}(s)/v_{in}(s)$$, I am not able to determine its zeros and poles.
$$Z_{1}=R_{2}\\
Z_{2}=\frac{1}{sC_{2}}\parallel R_{3}=\frac{\frac{1}{sC_{2}}\cdot R_{3}}{\frac{1}{sC_{2}}+ R_{3}}=\frac{\frac{R_{3}}{sC_{2}}}{\frac{1+sC_{2}R_{3}}{sC_{2}}}=\frac{R_{3}}{sC_{2}}\cdot \frac{sC_{2}}{1+sC_{2}R_{3}}=\frac{R_{3}}{1+sC_{2}R_{3}}\\
E_{TH}=E\frac{Z_{2}}{Z_{1}+Z_{2}}=E\frac{\frac{R_{3}}{1+sC_{2}R_{3}}}{R_{2}+\frac{R_{3}}{1+sC_{2}R_{3}}}=E\frac{\frac{R_{3}}{1+sC_{2}R_{3}}}{\frac{R_{2}(1+sC_{2}R_{3})+R_{3}}{1+sC_{2}R_{3}}}=E\frac{R_{3}}{1+sC_{2}R_{3}} \frac{1+sC_{2}R_{3}}{R_{2}+sC_{2}R_{3}R_{2}+R_{3}}=E\frac{R_{3}}{R_{2}+R_{3}+sC_{2}R_{2}R_{3}}\\
\\
Y_{R_{2}}=\frac{1}{R_{2}}\\
Y_{R_{3}}=\frac{1}{R_{3}}\\
Y_{C_{2}}=sC_{2}\\
Y_{TH}=Y_{R_{2}}+Y_{R_{3}}+Y_{C_{2}}=\frac{1}{R_{2}}+\frac{1}{R_{3}}+sC_{2}=\frac{R_{3}+R_{2}+sC_{2}R_{2}R_{3}}{R_{2}R_{3}}\\
Z_{TH}=\frac{1}{Y_{TH}}=\frac{R_{2}R_{3}}{R_{3}+R_{2}+sC_{2}R_{2}R_{3}}\\
\\
Z_{C_{1}}=\frac{1}{sC_{1}}\\
v_{in}(s)=\frac{1}{sC_{1}}i(s)+R_{1}i(s)+\frac{R_{2}R_{3}}{R_{3}+R_{2}+sC_{2}R_{2}R_{3}}i(s)+E_{TH}\\
v_{OUT}(s)=R_{1}i(s)+\frac{R_{2}R_{3}}{R_{3}+R_{2}+sC_{2}R_{2}R_{3}}i(s)+E_{TH}\\
K_{U}(s)=\frac{v_{OUT}(s)}{v_{in}(s)}=\frac{R_{1}i(s)+\frac{R_{2}R_{3}}{R_{3}+R_{2}+sC_{2}R_{2}R_{3}}i(s)+E_{TH}}{\frac{1}{sC_{1}}i(s)+R_{1}i(s)+\frac{R_{2}R_{3}}{R_{3}+R_{2}+sC_{2}R_{2}R_{3}}i(s)+E_{TH}} =\frac{i(s)\cdot (R_{1}+\frac{R_{2}R_{3}}{R_{3}+R_{2}+sC_{2}R_{2}R_{3}}+\frac{E_{TH}}{i(s)})}{i(s)\cdot (\frac{1}{sC_{1}}+R_{1}+\frac{R_{2}R_{3}}{R_{3}+R_{2}+sC_{2}R_{2}R_{3}}+\frac{E_{TH}}{i(s)})} =\frac{R_{1}+\frac{R_{2}R_{3}}{R_{3}+R_{2}+sC_{2}R_{2}R_{3}}+\frac{E_{TH}}{i(s)}}{\frac{1}{sC_{1}}+R_{1}+\frac{R_{2}R_{3}}{R_{3}+R_{2}+sC_{2}R_{2}R_{3}}+\frac{E_{TH}}{i(s)}}$$

Your circuit has a few nodes shorted together. If you're trying to match your calculations to your schematic, change the node names.

This is a good exercise for the fast analytical circuits techniques or FACTs as described in my last book. Provided the circuit is correctly drawn, meaning \$V_{out}\$ is probed after the dc-block capacitor \$C_1\$, then the transfer function (TF) is shown below:

I have considered \$V_{cc}\$ as a dc source hence its ac voltage is zero. It thus grounds the upper connection of \$R_2\$ and comes in parallel with \$R_3\$ and \$C_2\$. The expression I derived would need some rework to make it fit a low-entropy form.
Additional edit:
Following a discussion with D.A.S. in the comments section, I have added a simulation result which confirms my original ac response when the output of this filter is observed on the right-side terminal of capacitor \$C_1\$ as originally drawn. My final expression and the Mathcad plot reflect this. If \$V_{out}\$ is now observed across \$C_2\$, it certainly changes the response to that of a bandpass filter but it is not what the schematic shown in the first place:


Hello, Your plot needs to be reworked. Shown is lossless HPF, meanwhile the circuit is a lossy BPF

Hello, it corresponds to the arbitrary-selected values for the components but probably the caps are too low. I will see if I can update the charts this WE. Thank you for pointing this out.

YW.  The most obvious useful choice for a BPF is make all R, C values equal

Changing the components values does not change the overall shape. If you determine the limit of the transfer function I derived, the asymptotic gain when $s$ approaches infinity is 1 so no bandpass action and this is because of the $s^2$ term in the numerator. That is the reason why I asked the question if $V_{out}$ was really probed at the right side of the dc-block capacitor $C_1$.

Why did your plot show that you changed the value of R1 to 0 which converted it to a simple 1st order plot?  Thanks to Thevenin.

https://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$+0+0.000005+5+50+5+50%0A%25+0+16905175966.395636%0Ac+688+560+720+560+0+1e-10+0%0Ac+768+560+768+624+0+1e-10+0%0Aw+768+560+816+560+0%0Aw+816+560+864+560+0%0Ar+816+560+816+624+0+5000%0Ag+768+624+768+656+0%0Ag+816+624+816+656+0%0Ag+848+480+848+496+0%0A170+688+560+656+560+2+20+4000+5+0.1%0AO+864+560+912+560+0%0Ar+720+560+768+560+0+5000%0Ar+816+560+816+480+0+5600%0Aw+816+480+848+480+0%0As+720+512+768+512+0+1+true%0Aw+720+560+720+512+0%0Aw+768+560+768+512+0%0Ax+675+478+795+481+0+16+hello,+click+below%0A  Interactive solution

Well, if you do so ($R_1=0$), then yes, $C_2$ no longer contributes a zero but it was not the original circuit and the equation reflects a nonzero value for $R_1$.

you did not read/answer my question. Thankyou.

A simple bandpass filter features a zero at the origin and a double pole. If $R_1$ is zero, you see in the equation that the $s^2$ term goes to zero, leaving a single zero in the numerator. In that case, the plot would change and show a bandpass response. Is it what you were asking? Sorry if I misunderstood your point.

I understand all that but why do you show the wrong plot?

Ok, the plot is the frequency response of the TF that I derived which corresponds to the probe $V_{in}$ and $V_{out}$ shown in the original diagram. Since $R_1$ also appears in the attempt of deriving the TF, I assumed it was a non-zero value, hence my plots. If someone wants to plot the TF while $R_1$ is zeroed, I don't have an objection ^_^

I think you have it backwards.  Your plot has R1=0 whereas your text has it at 5k

Actually, even if $R_1$ is zeroed, you are left with a capacitive divider and the ac response does slightly change but the overall shape remains the same. I updated my answer by changing the $V_{out}$ probe position.

Thanks for clarifying. I misread where $V_{out}$ was located.  Yes, the Thevenin result is slightly different from the division yet still 1st order.  Did you like my simulation?  https://tinyurl.com/2m6k6zyh

The use of the switch is kind of funny but it works and nicely affects the Bode plot ^_^
